# Can a CPanel managed server only have one SFTP account?

Tags: cpanel, ftp

I use SFTP in Filezilla to transfer files to and from my web host.  But if I want to create an account for a vendor, it seems I am limited to FTP or FTPES.  I was told this was a restriction of CPanel managed servers.  Is this true?  Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Possible answer - create SSH keypairs: https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/getting-started-guide/accessing-your-account/setting-up-sftp-access-for-multiple-users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*SFTP is SSH file transfer protocol and it is an optional option*

- Some shared hosts disable SSH.
- Some shared hosts enable SSH.
- Some shared hosts will enable SSH it if you contact them.

*Setting up multiple users using multiple SSH Keys*

cPanel does allow technically allow for multiple SSH users by using multiple keys, however unlike FTP users, you are unable to restrict them to a given folder, instead, you are giving them full administration rights for the entire `/home/your-account` directory.

*Which includes:*

- `/home/your-account/mail`
- `/home/your-account/logs`
- `/home/your-account/public_html`

cPanel SFTP should only ever given to administrators of the account. If you want associated directories etc, then you should opt to use your own dedicated server or virtual machine.